# NLopt algorithm symbols and their use in Julia

Tags: julia

In Julia one can use NLopt to solve various problems. [NLopt](http://ab-initio.mit.edu/wiki/index.php/NLopt_Algorithms) has many algorithms and [here](https://github.com/JuliaOpt/NLopt.jl) we can find an example that utilises `MMA` using `LD_MMA` symbol.

My question is this: is there any complete list of all symbols incorporated in NLopt?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All the codes are listed in the [NLopt.jl source](https://github.com/JuliaOpt/NLopt.jl/blob/master/src/NLopt.jl), they are exactly like those described in that wiki page but without the `NLOPT_` prefix.

Comment: Thank you! That is indeed a list that has all the necessary information.